# Getting average of count(column) grouped by date, but meeting certain conditions

Tags: mysql, group-by, count, average, sql-date-functions

Data sample:

| dtime | id |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 06:00:00 | 1 |
| 2021-01-01 06:00:00 | 2 |
| 2021-01-01 06:00:00 | 3 |
| ... | ... |
| 2021-01-01 12:00:00 | 1 |
| 2021-01-01 12:00:00 | 2 |
| 2021-01-01 12:00:00 | 3 |
| ... | ... |
| ... | ... |
| 2021-01-12 20:00:00 | 1 |
| 2021-01-12 20:00:00 | 2 |
| 2021-01-12 20:00:00 | 3 |

In the real dataset, `id`s are between 1 and 9999, `dtime` are every 5 minutes, 24h/day, and I'd like to sample only at certain times (eg 06, 12, 16, 20h).

The expected output is the average of `count(id)` values, grouped by `DATE(dtime)`, but:

1. Only certain `TIME(dtime)` should be sampled (eg 06, 12, 16, 20h);
2. `count(id)` should ignore `id` that are not between 10 and 500;
3. `count(id)` should be discarded (and not considered for the average) if <3.

Output sample:

| DATE(dtime) | AVG(count(id)) |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 | 31 |
| 2021-01-02 | 29 |

So far I've got:

```
SELECT dtime,count(id)
FROM cron5min
WHERE (TIME(dtime) = '06:00:00' OR TIME(dtime) = '12:00:00' OR TIME(dtime) = '16:00:00' OR TIME(dtime) = '20:00:00') AND id BETWEEN 10 AND 500 AND estado = 1
GROUP BY dtime
```

and then I'm using PHP to do the average and discard data according to 3.

I'm now trying to do this with a MySQL statement only, no PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need 2 levels of aggregation:

```
SELECT DATE(dtime) date, AVG(counter) avg_count
FROM (
  SELECT dtime, COUNT(id) counter
  FROM cron5min 
  WHERE TIME(dtime) IN ('06:00:00', '12:00:00', '16:00:00', '20:00:00')
    AND id BETWEEN 10 AND 500 
    AND estado = 1 
  GROUP BY dtime
  HAVING counter >= 3
) t
GROUP BY date
```